# React Component with shared mouseOver handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, web-component

I have a simple react component that wraps the SVG 1.1 specifications `rect`tag and adds in some defaults and looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const defaults = {
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  width: 200,
  height: 100,
  rx: 0,
  ry: 0,
};

export default class Rectangle extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...defaults,
      ...props,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <rect
        {...this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </rect>
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to find a good way to add on a `mouseOver` function, but would like to do it in a way that can be reused with other components similar to this.

I have looked into Higher Order Components, but am having trouble when I try to set the state, because the state is not part of the above component's state.

Comment: what happens when you use mouseOver inside the shared component?

Comment: Try creating a class that does the common mouseover routine and then extend this class and the other classes from that one.